# JavaFX HTMLEditor text change listener

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm fairly new to the JavaFX world, and I can't seem to figure out how to listen for **text-modify** events in the **HTMLEditor** component.

I need this since I'm hooking this widget to a model, which needs updating.

The `addEventFilter` API, with a `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` event type doesn't seem to be working as it should. When its handler is called, the `getHTMLText()` isn't updated yet with the most recent character (if someone doesn't understand this paragraph, I'll provide a step-by-step example).

The **TextField** has a `textProperty()` on which a listener can be attached. 
Now what about the **HTMLEditor**?

Also, it would be nice to have the listener called ONLY on text modify events (and not on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, for example). You know... like SWT Text's `addModifyListener()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using JavaFX `HTMLEditor` in one of my project application, I also faced a similar situation. I ended up adding a `button`, upon whose click the parsing of the HTML text would happen, and further tasks executed. With `AnchorPane`, I was able to add the `button` on the HTMLEditor seamlessly, and it looked like a part of it.

Anyways, here's a little example of how you can achieve what you want without any extra button:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    try
    {
      final HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
      Scene scene = new Scene(editor);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);

      editor.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
      {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event)
        {
          if (isValidEvent(event))
          {
            System.out.println(editor.getHtmlText());
          }
        }

        private boolean isValidEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
          return !isSelectAllEvent(event)
              && ((isPasteEvent(event)) || isCharacterKeyReleased(event));
        }

        private boolean isSelectAllEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
          return event.isShortcutDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.A;
        }

        private boolean isPasteEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
          return event.isShortcutDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.V;
        }

        private boolean isCharacterKeyReleased(KeyEvent event)
        {
          // Make custom changes here..
          switch (event.getCode())
          {
            case ALT:
            case COMMAND:
            case CONTROL:
            case SHIFT:
              return false;
            default:
              return true;
          }
        }
      });

      primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Upon a bit more of thinking, I found a way to get event handling done even on those button clicks. Here's how:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseExitedHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event)
  {
    System.out.println(editor.getHtmlText());
  }
};

for (Node node : editor.lookupAll("ToolBar"))
{
  node.setOnMouseExited(onMouseExitedHandler);
}
```

If you see the `HTMLEditor`, it has two `ToolBars`.
What I'm doing in the code is `looking up` for those two toolbars, and setting an `onMouseExited` event handler. The analogy is that if the user enters and makes some changes on the HTML Text and exits the toolbar, an event will be fired, which can then be handled.

You can even set different kind of event handlers on these two toolbars, based on your needs, but in my opinion, these `onMouseExited` event handlers provide a very wide coverage when used with the `onKeyReleased` event handlers. The coverage based on `onMouseExited` handler is not exact though.

Comment: What about copy-paste? :-(

Comment: @GGrec: I've updated the answer to react to cut and paste events, and I'm sure you're smart enough to configure this low level key listener based on your own needs.

Comment: Oh man, this was obvious. I'm gonna throw another quick question, since it's on the same page. What about HTML changes? e.g. selected some text with the mouse, then changed to bold. The model should change, but it's not a type event.

Comment: @GGrec: Must say its an awesome question. Apparently, all the buttons and toolbar that you see in HTML editor are part of `HTMLEditorSkin` class, and those buttons are all declared private, so one can't access them. What I would have done in such a scenario is either build a custom HTML editor from scratch, by copying-pasting JavaFX source code for `HTMLEditor` and related classes, and then tweaking it appropriately. The second approach I would have taken is that I would have run a timer service on another thread, which would retrieve the HTML text every few seconds and parse it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple one

```
public class HtmlEditorListener {
    private final BooleanProperty editedProperty;

    private String htmlRef;

    public HtmlEditorListener(final HTMLEditor editor) {
        editedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        editedProperty.addListener((ov, o, n) -> htmlRef = n? null: editor.getHtmlText());
        editedProperty.set(false);

        editor.setOnMouseClicked(e -> checkEdition(editor.getHtmlText()));
        editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, e -> checkEdition(editor.getHtmlText()));
    }

    public BooleanProperty editedProperty() {
        return editedProperty;
    }

    private void checkEdition(final String html) {
        if (editedProperty.get()) {
            return;
        }
        editedProperty.set(htmlRef != null
                && html.length() != htmlRef.length()
                || !html.equals(htmlRef));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlEditor is based on Web view

```
    HTMLEditor editor = getEditor();
    WebView webView = (WebView) getEditor().lookup("WebView");
    new WebViewEditorListener(webView, new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

        }
    });
```

Add Callback for tracking html changes.

```
public static class WebViewEditorListener {

        private final ChangeListener<String> listener;

        private final WebPage webPage;

        private String htmlRef, innerText;

        public WebViewEditorListener(final WebView editor, ChangeListener<String> listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
            webPage = Accessor.getPageFor(editor.getEngine());

            editor.setOnMouseClicked(e -> onKeyTyped(webPage.getHtml(webPage.getMainFrame())));
            editor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, e -> onKeyTyped(webPage.getHtml(webPage.getMainFrame())));
        }

        public String getHtmlContent(){
            return htmlRef == null ? "" : htmlRef ;
        }

        private void onKeyTyped(final String html) {
            boolean isEqual = htmlRef != null ? htmlRef.length() == html.length() : html == null;
            if (!isEqual){
                String text = webPage.getInnerText(webPage.getMainFrame());
                listener.changed(null, innerText, text);
                innerText = text;
                htmlRef = html;
            }

        }
    }
```